# Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, c#-2.0

My class structure is as follows.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute("person", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Person : IDisposable
{
      Private int _id;
      Private string _name;

      [XmlElement(“id”)]
      Public int Id
      {
            Get{ return _id;}
            Set{ _id = value;}
      }

      [XmlElement(“name”)]
      Public string Name
      {
            Get{return _name;}
            Set{_name = value;}
      }
}
```

I am getting the following xml when I serialize the above class

```
<person> 
 <id>1</id>
  <name>Test</name>
</person>
```

Now, I would like to serialize the above class as follows i.e. I would like append “type” attribute for each public property that is serialized as xml element.  I can append “type” attribute to “person” node by declaring another public property “type” with “[XmlAttribute(“type”)]” but I would like to achieve the same for each public property that is serialized as xml element. Any idea to achieve below:

```
<person type=”Person”>
  <id type=”int”>1</id>
  <name type=”string”>Test</name>
</person>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things comes into my mind is to create a generic class, named for example **`Typed<T>`**, which looks like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Typed<T>
    {
        public Typed()
        {
        }

        public Typed( T value )
        {
             this.Value = value;
        }

        [XmlText]
        public T Value { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute( "Type" )]
        public String Type
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof( T ).Name;
            }
            set
            {
                // Skipped for clarity
            }
        }
    }
```

Then your **`Public int Id`**, becomes **`Public Typed<int> Id`**. There might be another way of doing this involving surrogates for the xml parser, but right now this is on top of my head.

Comment: +1 crazy alternative! ... add implicit conversions to / from the Typed<T> to T, and you get simpler use :)

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's answer is good, and very creative, but may involve refactoring code that you don't want to touch.  If that's the case, you might consider implementing `IXmlSerializable`.  It involves working directly with `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader`, but as long as you know the pitfalls of working with these classes (particularly `XmlReader`) it's not that bad and it gives you supreme control over the format of the XML.

If you want to get fancy you could even write an `XmlSerializationWrapper<T>` that implements `IXmlSerializable` and uses reflection to get the `[Xml...]` attributes of `T` and its members in order to determine how to format/read the XML, adding/using the *type* attribute. But at that point it's probably less crazy to just use Ivan's solution.

Comment: Sounds creative; i can well give it a try but then i have to decorate for all built in types. Is this the way to go about?

Comment: If you went the generic way, whether or not you would need to decorate for built-in types would depend on how you implement the discovery of serializable members. I would tend to handle it the same way the framework's serialization does: if a property is decorated with an XML attribute, serialize as indicated by the attribute; if decorated with XmlIgnore, don't serialize it; if undecorated, serialize using the property's name as the node name. Adding the type attribute is just a matter of writing out typeof(property).Name.